# JQuery datetime to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a web application where I wish to send information to a database.

I have a datepicker, which lets the user select a date and formats the date as `"YYYY-MM-DD"`. In addition to this, the users must also select a time using a `timepicker` which formats the time as `"HH:MM"`. This gets concatenated into a `DateTime` string as `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"`.

I need to convert this into milliseconds for the datetime to be accepted as the correct format on the database (locale format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.mmm`).

I have a tried a host of solutions found here and elsewhere to try and convert into milliseconds. Whenever I try to concat then convert I usually get a NaN error or "invalid Date" and I cannot simply add the converted milliseconds.

Is there any way of doing this in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: This is something that should be done on the server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to figure this one out myself. Thanks to those who answered. Its not an ideal solution, but it works.

```
var d = $("#date").val();
var dateParts = new Date((Number(d.split("-")[0])), (Number(d.split("-")[1]) - 1), (Number(d.split("-")[2])));
var dateis = dateParts.getTime();

var timeEnd = $("#endtime").val();
var time1 = ((Number(timeEnd.split(':')[0]) * 60 + Number(timeEnd.split(':')[1]) * 60) * 60) * 1000;

var timeStart = $("#starttime").val();
var time2 = ((Number(timeStart.split(':')[0]) * 60 + Number(timeStart.split(':')[1]) * 60) * 60) * 1000;

var dateTimeEnd = dateis + time1;
var dateTimeStart = dateis + time2;
```

What this basically does, is take a date from a datepicker, and a start and an endtime from a timepicker. The ajax accepts 2 datetimes, one for start, one for end. The above solution basically gets all the values from the input values, and converts it to milliseconds. It's not the best way of doing things but it is a quick fix.

Answer (score 6):

```
>> var datetime = new Date();
undefined
>> datetime.getTime();
1332613433314
```

> Date.getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01:

This should be handled server-side, though.

Comment: I tried something like this but I can only get it to work with the date portion only. Whenever I introduce the time section it says "invalid date"

Comment: Then *your* code smells, but my code is perfectly valid. Provide the string you are trying to convert to a Date object, and we can help.

Comment: var date1 = new Date($("#date").val()).getTime();
var timeend = $("#endtime").val();
var time1 = Number(timeend.split(':')[0]) * 60 + Number(timeend.split(':')[1]) * 1000;

var datetime = date1 + timeend;

I'm sure thats the one that fired the "invalid date"

Answer (score 3):

I don't realise your actual question, but I've made a code that set the datepicker to a minimum selected day as today the code is as follows :

```
$("#datefield").datepicker({
    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
    minDate:new Date(new Date().getTime())
});
```

The return value of the `new Date().getTime()` is the milliseconds from `1970/01/01 05:30 am` (as my system)

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the JavaScript Date object?

You could use it like so:
`var d = new Date(yyyy, MM, dd, hh, mm, 0, 0).getTime();`

You initialize the *Date* object and then use the *getTime* function to return the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970.

Answer (score 2):

$("#datefield").datepicker("getDate").getTime(); will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I would do this on the server side and use the [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert to a timestamp which will give you a number of seconds which if you really need milliseconds for some kind of script : 1 second = 1000 milliseconds.

If anything you could use jquery to validate that you'll be sending a valid date-time to the server side script before you do so.